# Display html text in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to display html strings in UITableViewCells.
I used this way:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p>";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

But it's very slow. Does anyone have another idea?

I read an article about using this: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText to display html string. But i don't know how to use.

Comment: Is the code you posted getting executed every time a cell loads?

Comment: yes. Because different text in different cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many third party classes are available for that like [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel). But internally all third-party classes are either converting HTML to attributed string or loading HTML into UIWebView. **BOTH WAY WILL WORK SLOWER IN TABLEVIEW CELLS**

If you are using HTML text in tableview cells then most convenient way is to make another array for just attributed string. Dont convert HTML to attributed string in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. When you are reloading table, make another saperate array just for attributed string by converting all HTML at once.

Load attributed string from your new array. It will load for first time, then it will work smoothly. You can handle one time loading by showing loader.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: But it'll spend a lot of memories

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be performing any heavy lifting inside your `cellForRow` method.

Instead, you should create each of your attributed strings, store them in an array, and use them when you need to in `cellForRow`.

```
textView.attributedText = self.myArrayOfStrings[indexPath.row];
```

`cellForRow` should only be reserved for setting properties, and possibly setting up the appearance of your cells. Never do any heavy calculations or animations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it helps...

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIWebView* webView = [[UISynchedWebView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.bounds.size.width - 20, cell.bounds.size.height - 20)];
        webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        webView.tag = 1001;
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        webView.opaque = NO;


        [cell addSubview:webView];
    }

    UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    webView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"current mode: %@", [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] currentMode]);

    [webView loadHTMLString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<head><body style=”background-color:transparent”><head><body>\
                              <i>this is very</i><b>very</b> <span style = \"font-size:120%%\">interesting text</span><br>row number: <b>%d</b></body>", indexPath.row]
                    baseURL:nil];


    return cell;
}
```

Reference: https://gavrix.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/uiwebview-inside-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

Only really working solution is `DTCoreText` right now.